# Iterate through list of Optional object

Tags: android, java-8, option-type

In the below posted code, I would like to know how can I iterate through a list of Optional objects?
According to the code:

```
OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getUser_3())
            .flatMap(user->user.getOptUserFavoriteTvList()
                    .filter(list-> list.get(???) != Optional.empty())
            );#
```

Now i want to refer to each index in the list? how can i achieve it?

**code**:

```
OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getUser_3())
            .flatMap(user->user.getOptUserFavoriteTvList()
                    .filter(list-> list.get(0) != Optional.empty())
            );


 private User getUser_3() {
    List<Optional<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
    list.add(Optional.of("espn"));
    list.add(Optional.of("Cnn"));
    list.add(Optional.empty());
    list.add(Optional.of("deutsch welle"));

    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName("johannas");
    user.setUserEmailAddres("joha90@gmail.com");
    user.setUserId("2005");
    user.setUserFavoritesTvList(list);
    return user;
}

public Optional<List<String>> getOptUserFavoriteTvList() {
    return OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getUserFavoriteTvList());
}
```

Comment: use your list using your getOptUserFavoriteTvList() method and iterate using for loop

Comment: What does `OptionalsUtils.toOptional` do? Looks like `Optional.ofNullable` is what you should  use instead of custom utility method.

Answer (score 1):

after `flatMap`, extract the list from the optional if present via `orElse` and then apply your logic...

```
OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getUser_3())
              .flatMap(user-> user.getOptUserFavoriteTvList())
              .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

after the call to `orElse`, you're now working with a `List<String>` which you can call `stream()` upon to perform more complex operations or iterate through it using a typical for loop etc...

---

you could even go with `ifPresent` if it's more suitable for the task at hand.

```
OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getUser_3())
              .flatMap(user-> user.getOptUserFavoriteTvList())
              .ifPresent(list -> list.forEach(e -> ....));
```